# nodejs android post request - unable to read params

Tags: android, node.js

I am trying to make a post request from an android application to my nodejs server but I can't read my post parameters, req.params are empty. Can anyone shed me some light? thanks a lot in advance.

```
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/vote', jsonParser,(req, res) =>{
    //do somthing
});
export default router;

//android below
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("test", "a");
        params.put("test2", 223);
        client.post(url2, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                Log.wtf("success", "hi: success");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                Log.wtf("failure", "hi: " + res);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you should use req.body.param_name to access post request params. for example req.body.test

Comment: Yes that's what i tried but it doesn't work, it's undefined